# Error: x and y must have the same first dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, signal-processing, dimensions

Error: raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but " ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (606976,)

I am getting this error when I run the plot bursts line of code in python: (all information for this line is below)

```
    plot_bursts((self.time_array), (self.data), (self.bursting), labels=['C4', 'Detected Burst'])

for i in range(len(self.data)):
            i += 1
            t = i/(2034.50521)
            self.time_array.append(t)


self.bursting = detect_bursts_dual_threshold(self.data, self.fs, 
self.amp_dual_thresh, self.f_range)




data_set = list(C4.items())
    C4 = np.array(data_set)
    C4 = C4[0][1]
    C4 = C4.flatten()
    np.array(C4)
    self.data = C4
```

not sure what to fix, please help thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but this indicates that you made a mistake when preparing the data to plot.

I assume you are using `matplotlib` under the hood. This message appears, for instance, when you pass vectors of different sizes to `plot`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1], [1,2])
```

Plot will attempt to match each element in x to exactly one element in y, and it will fail since the number of element in the two inputs are differetn.